# How to fix Python template tags for calling variables in HTML page, like {{ my_name }}

Tags: python, django

I created a variable in my python script. I want to display the value of this variable on my page. So I passed the variable to a dictionary and call the key on my HTML file. However, when I refresh my page it does not show any error and yet the value too does not show.
I am new to python, I do not know what the problem could be. Please is there any way to enable this template tag {{  }} before use?

Like so: Python function

```
from django.shortcuts import render


    def about(request):
        my_name = 'Hello! My name is Andi@ITech'
        return render(request, 'about.html', {"my_name":my_name})
```

HTML File

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} About Andi@ITech {% endblock %}

{% block content%}

<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a> | <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
<br><br>
<em>About Me</em>
<br>
{% if 2 > 21 %}
    Halo!
{% else %}
    GOODBYE
{% endif %}
<br>

{{ my_name }} <-- this line of code does not show anything -->

{% endblock %}
```

I expected the following sentence to display on my page
: Hello! My name is Andi@ITech.

Comment: Please, any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks good to me. Are you sure your block is executing correctly? It is enough that there is typo in the name of the base block (like `contetn`) and the block in the about.html file is not executed. It is also possible that the block is correctly executed but there is an error in the HTML and the browser does not show the text because it is inside a tag. Did you check the HTML resulting code? Also CSS can hide your text... It is not easy to give you a precise answer without all the code.

Comment: Okay, I will debug the code again. I thought probably for a fresh start I needed to do some configurations.

Comment: After going through the code over and over again, I got it running well after restarting the 'runserver'. Thanks so much